# Webpack 3 webpack-dev-server hot reloading does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I know this has been asked many times, but I just can't seem to find the right combination of tweaks to get this working.

Everything builds and everything runs. Webpack build output even shows that hot replacement is enabled. When I change a component, it rebuilds successfully...but nothing changes when I reload the page:

```
Version: webpack 3.10.0
Time: 359ms
        Asset    Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
 main.dist.js   5.7 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
main.dist.css  151 kB       0  [emitted]         main
 + 10 hidden assets
 [456] (webpack)/hot nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {0} [built]
 [911] ./node_modules/moment/locale ^\.\/.*$ 2.88 kB {0} [optional] [built]
[1004] ./src/components/admin/admin.js 3.77 kB {0} [built]
    + 1016 hidden modules
webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");

let plugins = [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("main.dist.css")
];

module.exports = {
    node: {
        fs: "empty",
        net: "empty",
        tls: "empty"
    },
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "assets/dist/"),
        publicPath: "./assets/dist/",
        filename: "main.dist.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: ["env", "stage-2", "react"]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: "style!css!resolve-url!sass?sourceMap"
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: "style-loader", use: ["css-loader"] })
            },
            {
                test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: "file-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"]
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        hot: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: "./"
    },
    devtool: "eval-source-map",
    plugins: plugins
};
```

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Routes from "./routes/index";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "../assets/css/styles.css";

ReactDOM.render(Routes, document.querySelector(".container"));
```

I've tried dropping my index.html file into the ./assets/dist folder and setting the contentBase to that folder:

```
devServer: {
    inline: true,
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: "./assets/dist"
},
```

It runs, but how reloading still doesn't work. No change.

Comment: could you show your index.js please

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko - Added. Can add the routes file as well, if needed.

Comment: I suppose you will have to follow the steps described here , alter weback entry point  and index.js

Comment: https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader

Answer (score 0):

The component that hold all pages/scenes in your app is blocking the update when the location changes.

That's because it isn't detecting any prop or state changes, so it's child components will no be re-rendered.

For example, if you are doing something like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div> 
        <NavLink to='/home'>Home</NavLink>
        <NavLink to='/login'>Login</NavLink>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

You can fix the issue by passing the `location` as a prop, so when the location changes the children will re-render. The simplest way to pass the location as a prop is:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

export default withRouter(App)
```

> Note: With more code of your project the answer will be more accurate. Please share a little bit more especially your `routeConfig`.